# TypeScript: Getting the type signature of values in a dynamically keyed object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, aws-serverless

I'd like to reference the value type in a type object I'm importing from a library and do not control.

I am using the serverless TypeScript package and it provides a type called `AWS` that looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  functions?: {
    [k: string]: {
      name: string;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I know can reference the type of the entire functions sub-object with `AWS["functions"]`

My question is, how can I programmatically ask for the sub-type of the *values* of that sub-object?

See the code below with "TYPE_HERE" indicating where I want to fill in the type.

```
import type { AWS } from "@serverless/typescript";

export default (): TYPE_HERE => ({
  name: "",
  ...
});
```

How can I state the type using the root type, or even the type `AWS["functions"]`, when it exists as the value property of a dynamic key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```typescript
interface AWS {
  functions?: {
    [k: string]: {
      name: string;
    }
  }
}

type FnType 
  = NonNullable<AWS["functions"]> extends { [K: string]: infer R } ? R : never

const d = (): FnType => ({
  name: "",
  dd: '', // error
});
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvpDAN)